# Why is $x(t)$ is $(k+1)$ continuously differentiable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, continuity

Hello in my ODE lecture I have the following statement but I don't see why exactly it's true:

Let the following first-order differential equation :

$$\dot x = f(t,x(t)) \tag{1}$$
Defined by the function $f(t,x)\colon \mathbb R \times \mathbb R ^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n  $ , s.t $f(t,x)$ is $k$ continuously differentiable for all the variables $(t,x_1,...,x_n)$

If we suppose that $x = x(t) \colon I \rightarrow \mathbb R^n  $ is a continuously differentiable solution of $(1)$. Hence $x(t)$ is $(k+1)$ continuously differentiable.

If anyone can explain why this statement is necessarily true it would be a lot appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that the derivative exists, since $\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x, t)$. Then the second derivative is... can you follow from that?

Comment: Take a look at the edit I just made - there's a much simpler way of displaying $\dot x = f(t,x(t))$ the way you want without adding lots of manual spaces.